# How to change hyperlink color dynamically in DataGrid in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hyperlink in DataGrid Control

[image]

What I want to do is that I need to change color of hyperlink dynamically (according to condition)

something like

If Status = Sign In then Username color should be with Green and if Status = Sign Out then Username color should be with Red.

I have tried with following but I couldn't get first column or text.

Same thing,  I can apply for rest of columns expect first one (for Hyperlink).

[image]

Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct two things here:

1. Cell Index is 0 based. You should have `rv.Row.ItemArray[2]` instead
   of `rv.Row.ItemArray[3]`.
2. Cells are referring to `<td>` rather than the `<a>` tag.

I would switch the class of `<td>` in code like this:

```
protected void dgBoundItems(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        if (rv.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString() == "Sign In")
        {
            e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "signin");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "signout");
        }

    }

}
```

And in my page I have added the css classes like this (in page head):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .signout a:link {
            font-weight:normal;
            color:red;
        }

        .signin a:link {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
       if (YourConditionOverHere){            
        e.Item.Cells[0].CssClass = HyperLink1.CssClass = "CssStyle2";
                else
                    e.Item.Cells[0].CssClass  = HyperLink1.CssClass = "CssStyle1";
        //Or you can use 
        //e.Item.Cells[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        //Or
        //e.Item.Cells[0].Color.FromArgb(0x0000aaaa);

    }
```